# Python's trigonmetric function return unexpected values

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

```
import math
print "python calculator"
print "calc or eval"
while 0 == 0:
    check = raw_input() #(experimental evaluation or traditional calculator)
    if check == "eval":
        a = raw_input("operator\n") #operator
        if a == "+":
            b = input("arg1\n") #inarg1
            c = input("arg2\n") #inarg2
            z = b + c
            print z
        elif a == "-":
            b = input("arg1\n") #inarg1
            c = input("arg2") #inarg2
            z = b - c
            print z
        elif a == "/":
            b = input("arg1\n") #inarg1
            c = input("arg2\n") #inarg2
            z = b / c
            print z
        elif a == "*":
            b = input("arg1\n") #inarg1
            c = input("arg2]n") #inarg2
            z = b * c
            print z
        elif a == "^":
            b = input("arg1\n") #inarg1
            c = input("arg2\n") #inarg2
            z = b ** c
        elif a == "sin":
            b = input("arg1\n") #inarg1
            var = math.degrees(math.sin(b))
            print var
        elif a == "asin":
            b = input("arg1\n") #inarg1
            var = math.degrees(math.asin(b))
            print var
        elif a == "cos":
            b = input("arg1\n") #inarg1
            var = math.degrees(math.cos(b))
            print var
        elif a == "acos":
            b = input("arg1\n") #inarg1
            var = math.degrees(math.acos(b))
            print var
        elif a == "tan":
            b = input("arg1\n") #inarg1
            var = math.degrees(math.tan(b))
            print var
        elif a == "atan":
            b = input("arg1\n") #inarg1
            var = math.degrees(math.atan(b))
            print var
    elif check == "calc" :
        x = input() #takes input as expression
        print x #prints expression's result
```

Isn't the sine of 90 degrees 1? 
With this it shows up as something around 51.2?
Google's calculator does this too?
BTW: this is my python calculator

```
            b = input("arg1\n") #inarg1
            var = math.degrees(math.sin(b))
            print var
```

This one and other trig functions are the problem.
For the most part, this was just a simple python calculator, but I wanted to add some trig functions.

Answer (score 10):

You don't want o convert the return value of `sin()` to degrees -- the return value isn't an angle.  You instead want to convert the argument to radians, since `math.sin()` expects radians:

```
>>> math.sin(math.radians(90))
1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Python's sin and cos take radians not degrees. You can convert using the math.radians function. Basically, you are using the wrong units.

Comment: Every language I know uses radians for trig functions, without exception.

Comment: @duffymo, I used a library once that used 0-256 sorta-degrees. But yeah pretty much anything uses radians.

Comment: Huh?  Please find a link to it.  I've written Fortran, Pascal, C, C++, Java, Python - all use radians.

Comment: @duffymo, here it is: http://alleg.sourceforge.net/stabledocs/en/alleg032.html#Fixed%20point%20trig

Answer (score 3):

Most math functions, including Python's math functions, use [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radians) as the measure for [trigonometric routines](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions).

Compare:

```
>>> math.sin(90)
0.8939966636005579
>>> math.sin(3.1415926535)
8.979318433952318e-11
>>> math.cos(180)
-0.5984600690578581
>>> math.cos(2*3.1415926535)
1.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using degrees, but the `sin` function expects [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) (see the documentation: `help(math.sin)`). 90° is /2.

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sin(math.pi/2)
1.0
>>> math.radians(90) - math.pi/2
0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert your input from degrees to radians before calling `math.sin`

Answer (score 2):

```
        var = math.degrees(math.sin(b))
```

This code does *not* do what you think it does. It takes the `sin` of `b` and then converts that answer (which is *not* in radians!) from radians to degrees.

The `sin` of 90 radians is `.894`. .894 radians is 51 degrees. So that's why you get that answer, but it's all wrong.

You probably want:

```
        var = math.sin(math.radians(b))
```

Comment: I got 0.0156031852817 when I id that, how do I get in to return degrees?

Comment: @user1080694 The value of sine mathematically is not degrees or radians, it is a periodic function that will oscilate between -1 and 1 with a period of 2*pi.  The inverse of the sine can be in degrees, but in python the math.asine function will be returned in radians, which you can then convert to degrees with math.degrees