# Not recieving correct output from python math code

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

Any ideas why the following code produces the wrong calculation? It's probably just incorrect syntax.

```
import math
ax = distance1 * math.cos(direction1)
```

`distance1` is set to 7600.
And `direction1` is set to 113.

In a normal calculator, 7600 times the cosine of 113 is equal to `-2969.556576518480538.`

But the code above produces `7564.02643525`.

Comment: The input to trig functions is an angle in radians.

Comment: try `ax = distance1 * math.cos(math.radians(113))` (or just know that `radians = degrees*PI/180.0`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python's trigonmetric function return unexpected values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483080/pythons-trigonmetric-function-return-unexpected-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`math.cos` and other trigonometric functions [take arguments in radians](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html#math.cos), not degrees.  You can use `math.radians` to convert.

```
ax = distance1 * math.cos(math.radians(direction1))
```

This produces `-2969.5565765184806` as expected